# Retrieve url that requires basic authentication

Tags: json, pentaho, basic-authentication

I'm kind of new to HTTP in general and basic authentication.

Anyway, I'm trying to use an open source data integration tool (Pentaho) to merge data from several different applications.

Anyway, things have been going smoothly except we changed one application to an online JSON database that requires basic authentication to access.

In this other XML database I'm accessing, I can simply pass the username/ password parameters into the url .... aka www.fakesite.com/database.xml?usr=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD.

I don't think this is how basic authentication works (I could be wrong). How would I pass my username and password into a HTTP header? Or would it be in the URL somewhere? Would I need to convert these strings to 64 bit code or whatever it is?

I may be able to do this in java or javascript before having pentaho fetch the resource, but I'm confused how this would work. would it be wwww.fakesite.com Basic 24309xdfs32e320 --- something like that? I'm confused how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try: http://username:password@example.com/

From: https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

> It is indeed not possible to pass the username and password via query
>   parameters in standard HTTP auth. Instead, you use a special URL
>   format, like this: http://username:password@example.com/ -- this sends
>   the credentials in the standard HTTP "Authorization" header.
>
> It's possible that whoever you were speaking to was thinking of a
>   custom module or code that looked at the query parameters and verified
>   the credentials. This isn't standard HTTP auth, though, it's an
>   application-specific thing.

Comment: This is probably correct, but the specific application I'm working with (Zendesk) instead of the basic username:password format, seems to use an emailaddress/token:password format. Aka /token is inserted in somewhere, and perhaps the / needs to be escaped. In other words, you're probably right, but someone designed something hopelessly complicated. Wish I could simply access a backend database easily --- I guess that's too much to ask with this software.

Comment: Adding another comment. Your answer worked, after much head-banging. For some reason doing username%2Ftoken   (they recommend a curl command that is USERNAME/token:password for who know's why) -- well entering that in place of what you told me, meanwhile escaping the backslash as %2F, somehow worked. Someone REALLY needs to build a front-end or even ... just something remotely comprehensible for database access. Yeesh. Thanks for the help though.